# Force page breaks and text containers using NSLayoutManager

Tags: swift, uikit, appkit, textkit

I'm trying to implement pagination using `NSLayoutManager` and multiple text containers. Creating `NSTextView`/`UITextView` instances works as expected, and the text flows from text view to another.

[image]

However, I'd like to force a page break, ie. determine myself where to break onto the next container. I'm working with parsed content, so I can't insert any additional ASCII control characters into the text.

I tried subclassing `NSLayoutManager` and overriding `textContainer(glyphIndex:, effectiveRange:)`, and here's a very brute-force example:

```swift
override func textContainer(forGlyphAt glyphIndex: Int, effectiveRange effectiveGlyphRange: NSRangePointer?) -> NSTextContainer? {
    if glyphIndex > 100 {
        return self.textContainers[1]
    } else {
        return super.textContainer(forGlyphAt: glyphIndex, effectiveRange: effectiveGlyphRange)
    }
}
```

I'd expect this to move any glyphs after 100th index onto the second container, but the results are weird:
[image]

I suppose I'd have to subclass `NSTextContainer` and tell the layout manager that it's already full of text. It has a method called `lineFragmentRect(forProposedRect:at:writingDirection:remaining:)` but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444555-linefragmentrect) is **very** sparse, and I can't find any working examples.

Existing documentation around displaying text is very outdated, so any ideas or hints are welcome. I'm very confused about this, but still hopeful there is a simple way of telling the layout manager where to cut off content in each container.

### One possible solution

`NSTextContainer.exclusionPaths` could be used to rule out the rest of the possible space in containers.

```swift
let glyphIndex = layoutManager.glyphIndexForCharacter(at: 100)
var rect = layoutManager.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: glyphIndex, effectiveRange: nil)

// Get the line range and used rect
var lineRange = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)
var usedRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect(forGlyphAt: gi, effectiveRange: NSRangePointer(&lineRange))

// Calculate the remainder of the line
let remainder = NSRange(location: glyphIndex, length: NSMaxRange(lineRange) - glyphIndex)

var rectCount:Int = 0
var breakRects = layoutManager.rectArray(forGlyphRange: remainder, withinSelectedGlyphRange: remainder, in: textContainer1, rectCount: UnsafeMutablePointer(&rectCount))

// Create the rect for the remainder of the line
var lineRect = breakRect!.pointee
lineRect.size.width = textContainer1.size.width - lineRect.origin.x
// Then create a rect to cover up the rest
var coverRest = NSMakeRect(0, lineRect.origin.y + lineRect.height, textContainer1.size.width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

// Add exclusion paths
textContainer1.exclusionPaths = [NSBezierPath(rect: lineRect), NSBezierPath(rect: coverRest)]
```

This results in expected behavior:
[image: Text breaking as expected]

This requires a ton of calculations, and text containers with exclusion paths are noticeably slower. The app could potentially have hundreds of text views, which makes this quite inefficient.

Comment: Have you looked at this article/tutorial? https://www.kodeco.com/578-core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app ... you might be able to "page-break" at, as in your example, every 100 glyphs.

Comment: I had *hoped* I didn't have to write my own Core Text framesetting because it's really poorly documented and I'm relying heavily on some other `NSLayoutManager` stuff, but this article makes it seem pretty straightforward. Thanks for the tip!